# Format CSS in jQuery Validate

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-validate

I want to view the text response of jQuery validate in a new line, not inline with the input elements.

How I can achieve it?

Code:
http://jsfiddle.net/5gVHx/2/

Press NEXT, you will see the validation response line in the same line as the input, i want it in a new line

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add `display: block;` to your `label.error` selector.

```
label.error {
    float: none;
    color: red;
    padding-left: .5em;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5gVHx/5/

Answer (score 3):

add the following option into your validation options

```
errorLabelContainer: "#errors"
```

where `#errors` is the selector of the element where you want to show the errors

Comment: Upvoted even though it doesn't strictly meet the OP, as it's a good technique none the less.

Answer (score 1):

just add a break to your statement

```
provincia: "<br />Por favor selecciona una provincia"
```

it shift to next line.